# Ceph Cluster - Reduced data availability: 96 pgs inactive And All OSD Nodes Are Down

Tags: ceph, healthcheck, object-storage

I set up my Ceph Cluster by following [this](https://docs.ceph.com/en/octopus/install/ceph-deploy/quick-ceph-deploy/) document. I have one Manager Node, one Monitor Node, and three OSD Nodes. The problem is that right after I finished setting up the cluster, the `ceph health` returned `HEALTH_OK` for all three nodes. However, when I get back to my cluster it wasn't ok. This is the output of the health check:

```
HEALTH_WARN Reduced data availability: 96 pgs inactive
PG_AVAILABILITY Reduced data availability: 96 pgs inactive
    pg 0.0 is stuck inactive for 35164.889973, current state unknown, last acting []
    pg 0.1 is stuck inactive for 35164.889973, current state unknown, last acting []
    pg 0.2 is stuck inactive for 35164.889973, current state unknown, last acting []
```

and also for all the other pgs.
I'm new to ceph and I don't know why this has happened. I'm using **Ceph version 13.2.10 mimic (stable)**. I have searched for an answer, but others who seem to have the same problem aren't experiencing node failure. All my osd nodes are down and this is the output for `ceph -s`:

```
  cluster:
    id:     xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx
    health: HEALTH_WARN
            Reduced data availability: 96 pgs inactive

  services:
    mon: 1 daemons, quorum server-1
    mgr: server-1(active)
    osd: 3 osds: 0 up, 0 in

  data:
    pools:   2 pools, 96 pgs
    objects: 0  objects, 0 B
    usage:   0 B used, 0 B / 0 B avail
    pgs:     100.000% pgs unknown
             96 unknown
```

I have also checked the osd logs and I didn't understand what the problem is, but these few lines indicate that there is the problem with my version of Ceph and I have to upgrade to luminous but I already have a newer version:

```
2021-02-18 22:01:11.994 7fb070e25c00  0 osd.1 14 done with init, starting boot process
2021-02-18 22:01:11.994 7fb070e25c00  1 osd.1 14 start_boot
2021-02-18 22:01:11.998 7fb049add700 -1 osd.1 14 osdmap require_osd_release < luminous; please upgrade to luminous
2021-02-18 22:11:00.706 7fb050aeb700 -1 osd.1 15 osdmap require_osd_release < luminous; please upgrade to luminous
2021-02-18 22:35:52.276 7fb050aeb700 -1 osd.1 16 osdmap require_osd_release < luminous; please upgrade to luminous
2021-02-18 22:36:08.836 7fb050aeb700 -1 osd.1 17 osdmap require_osd_release < luminous; please upgrade to luminous
2021-02-19 04:05:00.895 7fb0512ec700  1 bluestore(/var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-1) _balance_bluefs_freespace gifting 0x1f00000~100000 to bluefs
2021-02-19 04:05:00.931 7fb0512ec700  1 bluefs add_block_extent bdev 1 0x1f00000~100000
2021-02-19 04:23:51.208 7fb0512ec700  1 bluestore(/var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-1) _balance_bluefs_freespace gifting 0x2400000~400000 to bluefs
2021-02-19 04:23:51.244 7fb0512ec700  1 bluefs add_block_extent bdev 1 0x2400000~400000
```

I also checked the osd versions by `ceph tell osd.* version` and this is the output:

```
Error ENXIO: problem getting command descriptions from osd.0
osd.0: problem getting command descriptions from osd.0
Error ENXIO: problem getting command descriptions from osd.1
osd.1: problem getting command descriptions from osd.1
Error ENXIO: problem getting command descriptions from osd.2
osd.2: problem getting command descriptions from osd.2
```

while `ceph-osd --version` returns Ceph version 13.2.10 mimic (stable).

I can't understand what the problem could be. I also tried `systemctl start -l ceph-osd@#` and it didn't work. I have no clue what else I can try or why did this happen in the first place.

Comment: Please add the following output to your question:`ceph osd dump` and `ceph versions`.

Comment: @Shaghayegh Tavakoli: How did you restart the ceph ?from where ?
`systemctl start -l ceph-osd@#`

Answer (score 0):

I remember experiencing the same issue couple times.
Once the problem was the iptables, I forgot to open ports for cluster network on both monitors and OSDs.
The other time it was because my crushmap failure domain was set to host and I was running an all in one cluster, problem solved by setting crushmap to osd.